# Getting a, "ReferenceError: artificats is not defined" - Error running a simple "approver" test

Tags: contract-debugging, testing

(Working from the Lynda Ethereum course)

Running the test code below I get the following error:

> ```
> truffle tests
> Warning: Both truffle-config.js and truffle.js were found. Using truffle-config.js.
> Using network 'test'.
>
>
> Compiling your contracts...
> ===========================
> > Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
>
> /home/iii/Digital Ledger/contracts/migrations/2_depoly_contracts.js:1
> var ApprovalContract = artificats.require("ApprovalContract");
>                        ^
>
> ReferenceError: artificats is not defined
>     at /home/iii/Digital Ledger/contracts/migrations/2_depoly_contracts.js:1:24
>     at Script.runInContext (vm.js:107:20)
>     at Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:113:17)
>     at Object.file (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:354543:12)
>     at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:462577:24)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
> Truffle v5.1.15 (core: 5.1.15)
> Node v10.15.2
> ```

Here is the contract as well:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract ApprovalContract {

  address payable public sender;
  address payable public receiver;
  address constant public approver = 0xd268143B6FBD9BC6533F778052710C962eaAa68C;


  function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    sender = msg.sender;
    receiver = _receiver;
  }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
    return(approver);
  }

   function approve() external {
    require(msg.sender == approver);
    receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `artificats` to `artifacts`.